# Detectar cambio de location.href en un popup abierto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código.
Abro un popup al hacer clic en un botón y le paso una url que quiero que cargue.
Si la url del popup cambia, quiero decirle que cargue otra.

```
<input type="button" onclick="popup('https://www.marca.com')" value="Abrir popup">
<script>
function popup(url){
   var posicion_x = (screen.width/2)-(350/2); 
   var posicion_y = (screen.height/2)-(550/2); 
   var ventana = window.open(url, "Mi Ventana", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=550,top="+posicion_y+", left="+posicion_x);

   // AQUÍ QUIERO DETECTAR SI ventana.location.href CAMBIA, PARA PASARLE UNA NUEVA location.href
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que no puedes hacerlo. La referencia de ventana devuelta se puede utilizar para acceder a las propiedades y métodos de la nueva ventana, siempre y cuando cumpla con los requisitos de seguridad de la política de origen idéntico.

Esto significa que si llamas a window.open("/pagina.html"), obtendrás un objeto ventana completo, pero si llamas a window.open("https://www.marca.com"), devuelve sólo un objeto simplificado en el que no podrás añadir eventos. Esto es para prevenir [ataques de origen cruzado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)